# Why would laravel hash the password reset link in the database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

I'm completely new to laravel. So I'm trying to understand password reset system with `breeze` I was taken to this page after I click on an email link and I noticed this parameter
[image]

also ended up stumbling on probably the hashed version of the parameter inside the `password_resets` table
[image]

I get that this is for security reasons but I thought that token is completely useless after you hashed it cause you can't "unhashed" it, why would you do this?

Comment: hash can be used to check if password is correct by `Hash::check($plainText, $hashedText)` as said in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/hashing#verifying-that-a-password-matches-a-hash)

Answer (score 0):

It generates this hashed string to make sure that you're who owned the email and it doesn't reuse it afterward, because that's enough to let you set a new password. You requested for a reset password link, and you clicked on the link (so you access inbox messages) and that's it; It's you!